# shorten a multiple boolean operation to sort two sorted list

Tags: python

I write the following recursive solution to merge two lists:

The base cases are:

1) assert empty of both list

2)assert only one list is  not empty

3)decrease case to remove element

4) recursive case

```py
     def merge(l1, l2):
    """
    :rtype: List
    """
    global res 
    res = []
    #Base Cases 
    #1 assert  empty
    if len(l1) == 0 and len(l2) == 0: #
        return res 
    #2assert one not empty
    if len(l1) == 0 and len(l2) != 0:
        return res.extend(l2)
    if len(l1) != 0 and len(l2) = 0:
        return res.extend(l1)
    #3assert one element in both 
    if len(l1) = 1 and len(l2) = 1:
        if l1[0] < l2[0]:
            res.append(l1.pop())
            res.append(l2.pop())
        else:
            res.append(l2.pop())
            res.append(l1.pop())
        return res

    #4recur case
    else:
        return merge(l1, l2)
```

As for the `#2 assert only one is not emtty`, it 's cumbersome,
How could make the logic clear and concise?

Comment: you could do `if len(l1)*len(l2) == 0): return res.extend(l1).extend(l2)`. This should work because if only one is empty, you want the other one anyway, and extending an empty list will do nothing, so you'll get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shorten the code by using `all()`/`any()` and list comprehensions, and by not bothering with a separate variable `res`:

```
def merge(l1, l2)
    if not all(l1, l2):  # triggers when either l1 or l2 is empty
        return l1 + l2   # no reason not to just concatenate an empty list
    elif len(l1) == 1 and len(l2) == 1:
        # ternary if statement
        return [l1.pop(), l2.pop()] if l1[0] < l2[0] else [l2.pop(), l1.pop()]
    else: 
        return merge(l1, l2)
```